# mysql Automatic initialization and automatic update features for timestamp

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I an trying to insert timestamp data in to a mysql table using php, jquery and ajax, here I am using mysql Automatic initialization and automatic update features for timestamp. without ajax and jquery it's works fine.
This is the input form...

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="timein">Time In</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="timein" name="timein" placeholder="Time In">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" id="start_one" name="start_one" class="btn btn-success">Start</button>
 </form>
```

And this is the update.php

```
if(isset($_POST['start_one'])){
        $cabin = "cabin_one";


        querytwo("INSERT INTO ts(cabin) VALUES(:cabin)", array('cabin' => $cabin), $conn);

        $time_in = query('SELECT timein FROM ts WHERE cabin = :cabin ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1', array('cabin' => $cabin), $conn);

        if(!empty($time_in)){
            foreach($time_in as $start){
                echo $start['timein'];
            }
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve when i click the submit button the update.php runs through ajax and time stamp displays in the text input section.

Edit
This the script...The Ajax part I am not that much familiar

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start_one").click(function(){
      var myData = 'start_one='+ $("#start_one").val();
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        dataType: "text",
        data: myData,
        success:function(response){
          if(response.length > 0){
            $("#timein").append(response);
          }
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
          }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: you must provide the javascript code as well. Probably you don't send the `start_one` parameter when you are doing the ajax request

Comment: Exactly HOW is this not working?